Bash git prompt being really slow with git lfs
I have a folder with a 5 files saved with git lfs (about 3 Go).
I'm also using bash git prompt. It's working like a charm until I change the permissions of the files.
After entering a command and hitting enter, I immediately get the output of the command. However bash git prompt usually takes about 7 seconds to get display.
To stop the latency I have to do git update-index --refresh or git status however, git branch does not work.
What's even more strange is that if the permissions are 1001:1001 for example, doing chown -R 1001:1001 make the prompt slow again !
I don't understand why...
Ideally, I would like to prevent this behavior. Having to run git update-index --refresh after each permissions change isn't what I want to achieve.
Thanks.

The delay you’re experiencing likely stems from how Git handles changes to file metadata. Git tracks file permissions as part of its index, and when permissions change, it flags the files as modified, which can cause performance issues for operations like checking the repository status in your bash git prompt.
This behavior becomes noticeable with git lfs because it introduces additional checks on large files. Changing ownership (with chown) also updates metadata, triggering a similar slow-down since Git evaluates the repository state based on those changes.
To address this without running git update-index --refresh every time:

Avoid unnecessary permission changes: If possible, keep file ownership and permissions stable within your repository to minimize metadata updates.

Optimize Git performance for your prompt: Configure your git prompt to use lighter operations. For instance, instead of relying on git status, try using git branch or other faster commands. This adjustment can reduce the overhead.

Consider disabling permission tracking: You can use the core.fileMode configuration to tell Git to ignore permission changes:
git config core.fileMode false

This prevents Git from flagging changes in file permissions, but note that it only applies to chmod changes, not ownership changes (chown).


These steps should help. If the issue persists with large files, consider optimizing your LFS setup or exploring tools like direnv to isolate environments and permissions cleanly. So try this solution.

Thanks for your propositions.
About the 1, I need to change the perms
For the 2nd, It does not address issue as I want to use bash git prompt
The 3rd is a good idea, but I'm only using chown so... it don't work at all...
Do you have any other idea ?
